# Import new package to older release

Tags: packaging, development

I have uploaded a new package to Debian. It has recently reached Debian unstable and Ubuntu development branch (currently Vivid).

How do I get this new package into the currently supported stable Ubuntu releases (Utopic, Trusty, etc.)?

Do I request a sync or a backport?
It looks to me that I should request a backport (I can see some packages that only exist in *trusty-backports*, like *shellcheck*), but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, you'll have to follow the process to request a **Backport**:

> Backports must be approved by the Ubuntu Backporters team, but anybody
>   can request a backport. As backports require testing before they can
>   be approved, the backports team recommends that requesters of
>   backports also test them when possible.
>
> Backports are requested by filing a bug against the appropriate
>   backports project, as listed [here](https://launchpad.net/ubp). The Ubuntu Backporters team
>   recommends using the `requestbackport` tool in the `ubuntu-dev-tools`
>   package to file backport requests. This tool is aware of many
>   conventions for backports and can walk you through most of the
>   verification steps.

The detailed process is well explained [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuBackports).